# no consigo listar report, no recojo los datos

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

estoy intentando un listado sencillo con buscador en springboot y no consigo hacer el listado de report

view:

```
    <div layout:fragment="content" class="container sandstone">
     <form action="/report" class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group mb-2">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Search Title" />
         <input type="submit" value="Search"  class="btn btn-primary"/>
        </div>
     </form>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card card-body">
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Link</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Add</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr th:each="report:${reports}">
                        <td th:text="${report.date}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${report.title}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${report.link}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${report.description}"></td>
                        <td><a  th:href="@{/addReport()}" class="btn btn-dark">AddReport</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>

            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

controller:

```
@Controller
public class ReportController {

    @Autowired
    ReportService reportService;

    @GetMapping("/report")
    public String listReports(Model model, @RequestParam(defaultValue="")  String title) {

        model.addAttribute("report", reportService.findByTitle(title));
        return "views/listReport";
    }

    @GetMapping("/addReport")
    public String reportForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("report", new Report());
        return "views/reportForm";

    }
}
```

service:

```
@Service
public class ReportService {

    @Autowired
    private ReportRepository reportRepository;

    public void createReport(Report report) {
        report.setTitle(report.getTitle());
        report.setDate(report.getDate());
        report.setDescription(report.getDescription());
        report.setLink(report.getLink());
        reportRepository.save(report);  
    }

    public Report findOne(Long id) {
        return reportRepository.findOne(id);
    }

    public List<Report> findAll() {
        return reportRepository.findAll();
    }

    public List<Report> findByTitle(String title) {
        return  reportRepository.findByTitleLike("%"+title+"%");
    }
}
```

repository:

```
public interface ReportRepository extends JpaRepository<Report, Long>{

List<Report> findByTitleLike(String string);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

El problema creo que lo tienes en el Controller. Para mas filtrado en el siguiente GetMapping.

```
@GetMapping("/report")
     public String listReports(Model model, @RequestParam(defaultValue="")  String title) {
        model.addAttribute("report", reportService.findByTitle(title));
        return "views/listReport";
}
```

Podemos ver que buscar los `report` con `reportService` y lo nombras como `report` y luego en la vista le estas pasando "reports". Tendrías que cambiar a `<tr th:each="report:${report}">` o cambiarlo en el `@getMapping`.

El código corregido según mi criterio quedaría así:

VISTA:

```
<tbody>
      <tr th:each="report:${reports}">
         <td th:text="${report.date}"></td>
         <td th:text="${report.title}"></td>
         <td th:text="${report.link}"></td>
         <td th:text="${report.description}"></td>
         <td><a  th:href="@{/addReport()}" class="btn btn-dark">AddReport</a></td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
```

CONTROLLER (getMapping):

```java
@GetMapping("/report")
public String listReports(Model model, @RequestParam(defaultValue="")  String title) {

    model.addAttribute("reports", reportService.findByTitle(title));
    return "views/listReport";
}
```

Por si no has visto el cambio, he cambiado esta linea de codigo:

`model.addAttribute("reports", reportService.findByTitle(title));`.

Espero que le sea de gran ayuda.

Un saludo.

Comment: el tema es que eso lo había probado y al ponerlo así me casca            
THERE WAS AN ERROR |AN ERROR HAPPENED DURING TEMPLATE PARSING (TEMPLATE: "CLASS PATH RESOURCE [TEMPLATES/VIEWS/LISTREPORT.HTML]")| 500

Comment: Vale. Eso es porque no esta recogiendo los datos pero si los envía a la vista. El fallo esta en lo que devuelve el "findByTitle". Te recomiendo usar "findAll" para probar si es ese el fallo.

Comment: es como si me entrara vacío pero no está vacío

Comment: no entiendo que quieres hacer con este return: 
        return  reportRepository.findByTitleLike("%"+title+"%"); Pon simplemente title

Comment: es un buscador para que me saque los report buscando por title, pero si pongo un findAll() tampoco me salen

Comment: no veo necesario que tengas que poner esos % ya que los estas sumando al dato que te pasa el usuario para buscar en tu base de datos. Apenas de que en la base de datos lo tengas así claro.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90372/discussion-between-gonzalo-rodriguez-and-mantamusica).

Answer (score 0):

Gracias Gonzalo por tu ayuda, encontré la solución siguiendo el hilo de errores que quizás te hubiera ayudado.

El Thymeleaf cascaba al no poder leer en la vista la orden del botón

```
<td><a  th:href="@{/addReport()}" class="btn btn-dark">AddReport</a></td> -->
```